# get a specified element using regex - PHP

Tags: php, regex, .htaccess, preg-match

I'm trying to get a name of a page in a `.htaccess` file using `regex`, here's the line :

```
RewriteRule ^test.html$                                     /public/index.php?test=$1
```

And I'm trying to retrive the `test.html`. Here's what I've tried so far and didn't quite work :

```
preg_match('/\b\^[\w%+\/-]+?\$\b/', $input, $matches);
```

Any help with this? I'm struggling when it comes to regex! Much appreciated.

Comment: How are you using this information? Extracting the regular expression doesn't seem all that useful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to remove the `\b` (which matches between a word character and a non-word character) from your original regex. Because there isn't a word boundary exists between `space` and `^` symbol. And also you need to include the dot inside the char class.

```
preg_match('~\^([\w%+\/.-]+?)\$~', $input, $matches);
```

Use the above regex and then get the string you want from group index 1.

[DEMO](https://www.regex101.com/r/tI8nV7/6)

OR

Use lookarounds.

```
preg_match('~(?<=\^)[\w%+\/.-]+?(?=\$)~', $input, $matches);
```

[DEMO](https://www.regex101.com/r/tI8nV7/7)